# powerpoint before print

Tags: powerpoint, addhandler

I can get winword and excel beforeprint events, but in powerpoint I can't.

Can anyone show me a link that points me when the slides or presentation beforeprint

in powerpoint:
how?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chirag Dalal has a useful list of PowerPoint events, which versions support them and when they occur here:

http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/events_version.html

Unfortunately, there's no BeforePrint event.

Comment: any idea or recommendation to get what i want?

Comment: I suppose it'd depend on what you need to do.  Can you explain what you're after in more detail?

Comment: Ok, for users that can only print in a specific folder, if they can print(with powerpoint only)maybe a pagesetup error?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the explanation of what you're after.

Comment: What I am trying to say is, the user can't print the document if the document file is not in a registered folder.  And, So, I got, word ,excel and publisher working but on powerpoint I can't, do you have any idea that the user could not print in powerpoint?  OR if they could print there will be an error.  Thanks.

Comment: All I can think to do is remove the existing print buttons from the ribbon/toolbar and replace them with your own routines.  I don't believe there's anything you can do about the built-in keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+P)

Comment: Yes, I though about that also, but I may need to override the readonly mode of commandbar.  Thank you very much.